# Set Ant property from Gradle not working

Tags: ant, gradle

I'm converting our build from Ant to Gradle.  Our first step is to add the Gradle build files so we can start using Gradle as our build tool.  This lets us use our existing build scripts to build using Ant and convert them to Gradle over time.  I want to simply have Gradle call the existing Ant build files.  Our projects are all NetBeans projects, which have build.xml and nbproject/build-impl.xml files.  Some of the projects require NetBeans build properties, which can be found at ~/.netbeans/6.5.1/build.properties.  I currently have build.gradle which contains only this:

```
ant.importBuild 'build.xml'
```

I can build the project using Ant like this:

```
ant -Duser.properties.file=/home/me/.netbeans/6.5.1/build.properties dist
```

However, when I build with Gradle, Ant complains it cannot find the properties set in build.properties.  I've tried setting the Ant property, but it doesn't seem to get picked up:

```
ant.properties['user.properties.file'] = '/home/me/.netbeans/6.5/build.properties'
```

I've also tried setting a system property:

```
systemProperties 'user.properties.file': '/home/me/.netbeans/6.5/build.properties'
```

but this doesn't work either.  Ideally I'd like to set this property in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties as just about all of our projects need it.

How can I set this property in Gradle and have Ant pick it up when called from Gradle?

Comment: Have you tried to place `ant.properties` before `ant.importBuild`?

Comment: Thanks!...that worked in the project's build.gradle file.  However, I have the property set in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties and in the top-level build.gradle file.  Why aren't these being picked up?  I need this property set in almost all of the projects, so I'd like to set it once, especially since this is user-specific.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are saying, but `ant.properties` is per *project*. Of course you can do something like `allprojects { ant.properties[...] = ... }`.

Comment: If ant.properties is per-project, that may explain why it isn't working.  What I'm saying is I have a repository with multiple projects in it, all of which are Ant projects.  Just about all of them require the Ant user.properties.file property to be set.  I would like to set this Ant property in one place, say in the gradle.properties file or in the build.gradle file at the top of the repo.  If I take the approach of adding ant.properties before the ant.importBuild, I'll have to add the property to all build.gradle files. (cont'd.)...

Comment: The property is user-specific (/home/<username>/.netbeans/6.5.1/build.properties. So every developer will have to modify all of the build.gradle files to set this property to build.  I'd like to set it in one place, and reference it in all build.gradle files.  Any way to do that?

Comment: As I said, you can do `allprojects { ... }` in the top-level `build.gradle` file. `properties.gradle` isn't suitable because it sets Gradle (project) properties, not Ant properties. You should also think about a way to avoid the need for every developer to customize the build script(s). For example, you can get the (OS) username with `System.getProperty("user.name")`.

Comment: Hi Peter, yes it does work.  It turns out my problem was that I needed to include this particular project in my top-level settings.gradle file so the top-level build.gradle file was processed.  And thanks for the System.getProperty suggestion, this is what I was looking for also.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set load the properties on multiple Gradle projects you could use a Gradle init script, http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/init_scripts.html. Inside the init script you would put this code:

```
allProjects {
    ant.properties['user.properties.file'] = '/home/me/.netbeans/6.5/build.properties'
}
```